# How to do a multiple select with raw query using Eloquent in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I made a query which gets all the column data of a table and an additional custom column aliased as 'distance'. Right now the query looks like this:

```
$restaurants = DB::table(DB::raw('restaurants'))
    ->select(
        'restaurants.id',
        'restaurants.name',
        'restaurants.about',
        'restaurants.contact_details',
        'restaurants.address',
        'restaurants.city',
        'restaurants.lat',
        'restaurants.long',
        'restaurants.cuisines',
        DB::raw(*some computation here* . " as distance")
    )
    ->get();
```

Basically, my query should look like this in SQL:

`SELECT *, *some computation here* as distance FROM restaurants`

Is there a way to simplify this using Eloquent? Right now I need to manually specify all the columns just so I could add the DB::raw select statement.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but maybe this will work for you: $restaurants = DB::table('restaurants')
    ->select('restaurants.*', DB::raw(*some computation here* . " as distance")    )
    ->get();

Comment: @ThomasSnijder Yes, that worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
$restaurants = DB::table('restaurants')
    ->select(
        'restaurants.*',
        DB::raw(*some computation here* . " as distance")
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: Haha, can't believe I missed this one. Thanks! :D